# IOS deployment error [PAClient Error] Error: E0776

Tags: delphi

I was asked a question because the error could not be resolved during IOS app development and distribution...

(I tried googling my own to solve it, but it was my first time on the IOS side, so I got to seek help due to limitations.

The Delphi version is 10.4.

If you compile with IOS Device 64-bit = Configuration = Development, it compiles well on the iPhone device,

Development continued.

[Provisioning has been set up for all (Application Store, Development, Ad hoc ), and I checked the option to connect the certificate. ]

To register on the App Store

When distributing Ad hoc or Application Store, the following error occurs.

================================================== ============

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ** EXPORT FAILED **

 

[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: Couldn't load -exportOptionsPlist: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

 

[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not a valid property list.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Encountered unexpected character A on line 14 while looking for close tag" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Encountered unexpected character A on line 14 while looking for close tag, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Malformed data byte group at line 1; invalid hex" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Malformed data byte group at line 1; invalid hex}})))

 

================================================== ==========


Xcode version is 11.7, iOS software version is 13.7.
```

@Deployment@

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co0ZN.png)

Comment: Delete the `info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml` file, and the `LaunchScreen.TemplateiOS` folder, and rebuild. If that does not work, after building, use `Project|Deployment` in the Delphi main menu, and check whether there are many disabled entries. If so, use the "Revert to default" button (looks like "Undo") in the top left

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
-Remove iOS Device 64 folder
-Remove LaunchScreen.TemplateS folder
-Remove Entitlement.TemplateiOS.xml file
-Remove info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml file
All icons and images have been changed to default.
"Revert to default" button
Project -> Build => Ok
Project > Deployment -> Deploy => I got the same error though...
Is there any way I can try more..??